# how to change session value every time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a splitter.

In the left pane of the splitter I have a grid and in the right pane I have tabs.

I put selected record in the grid  ID value in the session like 
`sessionStorage.setItem("ID",id)`. passing this id value to the right side tabs and displaying tab content depending upon ID.

For the first selected record,it is displaying with that particular id value,If I select different record in the grid then also the Id value is not passing to the tabs and displaying the content with first selected record id.

Comment: session value will be updated only when load or Postback happens i.e. page is posted to server. when you select a particular record from the grid, does postback happens? or wat?. make sure, your code on the server( codebehind) gets executed everytime you change the selected Item

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario,

Use queryString and redirect current page.

```
Response.Redirect("current.aspx?id"+ID)
```

Then, Pass value ID in TAB pane

```
int ID =  int.parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```